# Parse Android Facebook sign up not saving name/email

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, back4app

I have got my Parse stuff running on Back4App. I have gotten Facebook signup/login working that goes through Parse and authenticates with Facebook, if the user doesn't exist in the Parse user table it creates the entry. User can then login/logout on the Android app fine, all working.

The problem I'm having is Parse is not saving the username/email it first retrieved from Facebook, it's saving a session token in the username field (or some other value I'm unsure of). I want it to save the user's email and name retrieved from Facebook in the _User table.

I can see when I trace the code in Android Studio it can see my full name, email, etc pulled from Facebook but it's not putting that info into the Parse _User table.

eg when I signup to the app using my facebook account:

[image]

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(Login.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                        getUserDetailFromFB();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CategoryList.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        getUserDetailFromParse();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CategoryList.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

void getUserDetailFromParse(){
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mUsernameField.setText(user.getUsername());
    mUsernameField.setText(user.getEmail());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome Back!" + mUsernameField.getText().toString() + " Login.Email:" + mUsernameField.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

void getUserDetailFromFB(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try{
                FbUsername=(object.getString("name"));
                //FbUsername=response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                FbEmail=response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            saveNewUser();
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","name,email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
void saveNewUser(){
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    user.setUsername(FbUsername);
    user.setEmail(FbEmail);


    //user.put("email", FbEmail);
    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " +FbUsername+"!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, the code above works 100% for others looking. My error was with Parse - I already had my email address in the _Users table as I previously made an account and authenticated with Parse directly.

According to the Parse logs it couldn't set my email address for a new user because the user already existed in the table.